# convert a column (of numbers) of a cell from number to string

Tags: matlab, sorting, cell-array

In Matlab, I have a problem where I want to sort a cell w.r.t a column of numbers. however the sortrows function doesn't work (I get this error:Some cells in X contain non-scalar values and cannot be sorted). I suspect that I need to convert the column of numbers to a string type.

So my question is how can I convert only 1 column of the cell to type string?

Edit:

First 4 rows of cell:

```
cell_1 = {' 1996Q1' 0.009  0.009  54594;
          ' 1996Q2' 0.011  0.013  54594;
          ' 1996Q3' 0.010  0.010  54594}

[K,I]=sortrows(cell_1,4);
```

Comment: Can you add an example for the cell and the code you have already tried?

Comment: I have added an example for the cell and the code

Comment: After which column do you want to sort? `4`th column? I assume then, you have there different values than in your example.

Answer (score 0):

You can grep only the column you want to use and sort this in numerical context. See example below (I changed the values in the forth column to show the effect).

```
cell_1 = {' 1996Q1' 0.009  0.009  54594;
          ' 1996Q2' 0.011  0.013  54592;
          ' 1996Q3' 0.010  0.010  54593};

[~,ind] = sort([cell_1{:,4}])

ind =

     2     3     1

cell_2 = cell_1(ind,:)

cell_2 = 

    ' 1996Q2'    [1.1000e-002]    [1.3000e-002]    [54592]
    ' 1996Q3'    [1.0000e-002]    [1.0000e-002]    [54593]
    ' 1996Q1'    [9.0000e-003]    [9.0000e-003]    [54594]
```

Comment: or `cell2mat(cell_1(:,4))` to get the the fourth column as a vector